# java encoding issue while writing file

Tags: java, file, encoding

I am creating a very simple application which reads some input from one file and generates another file with that information. I ran it on Windows 7 and it worked with no problems, but when I run it on Mac OS, special characters are not shown properly.

Here is my code:

```
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(destiny),"utf-8"));
writer.write(infoFromInputFile);
writer.close();
```

I am declaring my FileOutputStream with UTF-8 codification, and when I checked the created file properties, it says that it is in UTF-8, but the special characters like ¿, á, é, í, ¡, etc. are displayed wrong.

Any ideas of why is this happening?

Comment: And what is `infoFromInputFile`? Where does it come from? Does your terminal have support for displaying the characters you mentioned?

Comment: infoFromInputFile is a String with special characters. I printed it on console and it was shown propperly.

Comment: Please do not paraphrase important information, such as "special characters like ...".  Do a copy/paste to show EXACTLY what you see, preferably in a code block (indent 4 spaces), and also tell us where/how you are displaying the data.  It is highly likely that the output is actually correct, and whatever is displaying the data does not support UTF-8.

Comment: Hmm.  When you say "when I checked the created file properties", what exactly do you mean by "properties"?

Comment: Ok, this is exactly how I read the file class:

`private  ArrayList<String> openFile(String file) throws IOException{
  ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  
  String line = br.readLine();
  
  while(line != null){
   content.add(line);
   line = br.readLine();
  }
  br.close();
  return content;
 }
}`

Comment: This is how I create my output file
`public void divideWords(String origin, String destiny) throws IOException{
  ArrayList<String> lines = openFile(origin);
  Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
       new FileOutputStream(destiny), "utf-8"));
for (String line : lines) {
writer.write("\t\t\t\t<span id=\"palabra"+ wordCt++ +"\">"+ word +"</span>");
writer.close();
}`

Comment: to check the file encoding, i used the command:
`file --mime file.txt`

Comment: And if the input file has the text: 

"Aquí está el párrafo", the output in Mac is "<span id="palabra1">Aqu√≠</span><span id="palabra2">est√°</span><span>el</span><span>p√°rrafo</span>"

Comment: Are you sure that whatever you're using to display the results actually supports UTF8? Those two-character sequences look suspiciously like legitimate UTF-8 encodings of non-ASCII characters displayed byte-for-byte in an 8-bit-character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

How did you check the output file?  Perhaps the editor you opened it with, or the command you dumped it to the console with (or the console itself), incorrectly rendered the content of the file?  (That is, perhaps the file is correct, and the thing you checked it with assumed it wasn't UTF-8.)

Alternatively, are you sure you opened the input file (presumably using a `Reader`?) with the correct encoding?

You need to check a number of things:

- First, I'd recommend calling `flush()` on the Writer, before you close it.
- What was the actual encoding of the original file (the input file)?  Were the input file(s) in two different encodings (one on Windows, a different one on Mac)?  Or the same (maybe UTF-8 on both)?  I'm guess the default encoding (the one that Java assumes, if you don't tell the Reader) might be different on Windows and Mac (or even between versions).
- What encoding did you open the input file as, when you read it?  (This should match what it was re the above).
- Did you do anything between input and output, when processing the file, that might have introduced odd characters?  (Like, for example, doing arithmetic on Unicode values.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Mac uses a different codification for .java files than Windows and Linux (which I als tried and worked well). To create files with UTF-8 encoding, you must run your program with the following option:

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 YourJavaClass`

Thanks for your help.